# Tribes Ascend Graphical Errors

Tags: graphics-card, tribes-ascend

I dont know why, my game most of the time looks like this...

[image]

Here are my specs... if they can play a role in this.

```
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 940 @ 2.93GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.9GHz
Memory: 6144MB RAM
Hard Drive: 984 GB
Video Card: ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series 
Operation System: Windows 7
```

Comment: I assume you've got the latest drivers? Other than that I would try a clean install. I know it sucks but it seems to be the only recourse sometimes.

Comment: Just did the checkup, yes, I'm on the highest version of the driver available.

Comment: I had this problem when my ex-video card overheated while playing any 3d game for a prolonged period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that either you need newer drivers for you GPU or you GPU isn't supporten.

The specs:

http://hi-rez.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/269/~/what-are-the-minimum-and-recommended-system-requirements-for-tribes%3A-ascend%3F

You card (not sure if this also counts for mobile versions of the card):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_R700

So it has Shader Model 4.1, which is enough (again if it's not a special mobile version which is different).

And you are sure you have the latest drivers from AMD?

You can fill out this and get the latest (I didn't know if you had Win/ 32 or 64bit):
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Otherwise there is an autodetect program that should help you:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/auto_detect.aspx

I hope this helps,

Christian

Comment: I just had to downgrade my Driver (from Catalyst Suite 14.3 to 14.2) and it got rid of them. Thanks for the infos.

Comment: @Fredy31 Ok glad it help, though it sounds strange you have to downgrade, unless it was Beta drivers.